# spring mvc pass &amp; in queryString

Tags: spring, servlets, servlet-filters

I would like to pass in queryString like following in Spring MVC

```
?search="This &amp; That"&value=true
```

But, when I am trying to access HttpServletRequest, it returns only "This " for "search" parameter. Any idea how to achieve this?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

your queryString should be

```
?Search=This%20&amp%20That&value=true
```

to search for **This & That** string